# How to make an input field revert to "pristine/untouched" once filled in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have an input in a modal box and I want to revert it back to pristine once I click the "ok" button.
I'm making some sort of to do list in which everytime I fill an input and click the "ok" button the value I've written gets saved in a list.

The problem is that I want to keep the "ok" button disabled everytime the input "refreshes" thanks to `(click)="task.value = ''"` and that only works at the start when the page gets refreshed.

Once I type anything it becomes "dirty" and "touched", i assume I'm supposed to make it stay "pristine/untouched"?

HTML:

```html
<div class="modal">
    <p>What did you do?</p>

    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="activity.name" #task />
    <button
      (click)="addTask(task.value)"
      (click)="task.value = ''"
      [disabled]="activity.name === ''"
    >
      OK
    </button>
  </div>
```

TS:

```js
activity: Activity = {
    name: '',
  };
  addTask(item: string) {
    this.list.push({ name: item });
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well this is not a form, so it cannot be made pristine or untouched.

Your button is currently disabled when `activity.name` is an empty string, after you press the button you set `task.value` to an empty string. That is not the same thing as your object `activity`. If you want to achieve the same, you need to actually set the `activity.name` to an empty string for your condition to be fulfilled. As we are using two-way-binding you can also do this in your addTask function. I would just do:

template:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="activity.name" />
<button (click)="addTask()" [disabled]="!activity.name">OK</button>
```

TS:

```
addTask() {
  this.list.push({ name: this.activity.name });
  this.activity.name = '';
}
```